# How $.parseJSON() parses an array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I get an array from mysql query  in test.php

`$rows =Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => nikhil ) [1] => Array ( [name] => akhil ))`

I convert it into json format string and echo it

```
$jsonstring = json_encode($rows);
echo $jsonstring;
```

OUTPUT :

> [{"name":"nikhil"},{"name":"akhil"}]

I know this is still not in json format but it is an array(of json)

But now i can use `$.parseJSON` in `jquery.php`

```
 $.post("/test.php",function(r){var jsonobject = $.parseJSON(r); 
    for(var i=0;jsonobject[i];i++){
  $("#userslist").append("<br>" + jsonobject[i].name);}
```

and it parse it properlly , and i can access this json  object as well , but as we know

`$.parseJSON()` converts only well formed json string into object. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

> $.parseJSON(): Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript value.

so how `$.parseJSON()` parse an array ? any ideas?

Comment: That "output" array **is** JSON.

Comment: It's valid JSON format as it includes arrays: http://www.json.org/

Comment: it is not an json , it as an array , A proper json would be `{"users" :[{"name":"nikhil"},{"name":"akhil"}]}`

Comment: @beginner no, that's incorrect. An array is a perfectly good JSON value.

Comment: @beginner that assumption about JSON is incorrect. Even a JSON structure consisting of nothing but a string literal is valid JSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A JSON value can be:

- A number;
- A string;
- The values `null`, `true`, or `false`;
- An array of JSON values;
- An object consisting of string property names and JSON values for each.

So

```
[{"name":"nikhil"},{"name":"akhil"}]
```

is a perfectly good JSON value. It's an array containing two values, each of which are objects with a single property having a string value.

Comment: You said JSON value , what u mean by json value, I think in `{"users" :[{"name":"nikhil"},{"name":"akhil"}]}` JSON value is an array , which is all right

Comment: @beginner no, that is simply not correct. An array is definitely a valid JSON value, and the fact that `JSON.parse()` is able to parse it should be all the evidence you need.

Comment: Thanks ,, I read somewhere that Array is not a json , and json should be only in the `{"name":"value"} `  format  . and i was very convenced .  Happy to know my assumption was wrong